# pandas module installed in miniconda but python3 can't run the coding

Tags: python, pandas, miniconda

I have pandas module installed in miniconda but python can't run the coding.

Error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

[image]

I am new to programming and I have no clue on what happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally notice this problem is due different environment. 
IDLE that i using on left figure is stand alone and miniconda it self has another IDLE in miniconda environment.